# Error The System Cannot Find The Specified File

Tags: python, windows

I have a problem with my Python File. I don't know how to fix it, I tried fixing it but didn't work

When I tried to run the file, it just appears an error

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\accbr\OneDrive\Dokumen\GitHub\PocketMine-MP-Installation\.setup\setup_pmmp_windows.py", line 82, in <module>
    phpextract()
  File "C:\Users\accbr\OneDrive\Dokumen\GitHub\PocketMine-MP-Installation\.setup\setup_pmmp_windows.py", line 24, in phpextract
    with zipfile.ZipFile('PHP-8.0-Windows-x64.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 1240, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PHP-8.0-Windows-x64.zip'
```

My python file path in my user:
C:\Users\accbr\OneDrive\Document\GitHub\PocketMine-MP-Installation.setup

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import time
import sys
import requests
import subprocess
import zipfile

def slowprint(s):
    for c in s + '\n':
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(5. / 100)

def clear():
    os.system("cls")
    
def wgetwindowsdownload():
    URL = "https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/1.21.3/64/wget.exe"
    response = requests.get(URL)
    open("wget.exe", "wb").write(response.content)

def phpextract():
    with zipfile.ZipFile('PHP-8.0-Windows-x64.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall('PMMP-Server')

clear()

slowprint("Starting the setup...")
time.sleep(5)
clear()

slowprint("Welcome to PocketMine-MP Installation (64-bit) - Windows")
slowprint("Copyright 2022 KeenTeams - PocketMine-Setup v1.0.1")
print(" ")
print("-------------------------------------")
print(" ")
slowprint("Created by Keenan Yafiq (keenanyafiqy)")
slowprint("Executed from Python")
slowprint("This installation will install PocketMine-MP v4.x.x into your machine")
print(" ")
print("-------------------------------------")
print(" ")
choice = input("Do you want to start the installation? [y/n]: ")
if choice == 'n' : sys.exit()
if choice == 'y' : clear()

slowprint("You will download:")
slowprint("1. wget for Windows")
print(" ")

choice = input("Start the setup? (Typing 'n' will cancel the setup!) [y/n]: ")
if choice == 'n' : sys.exit()
if choice == 'y' : clear()
slowprint("Starting setup...")
slowprint("Downloading 1 tools (wget)...")
wgetwindowsdownload()
slowprint("Creating a folder for 1 tools (wget)...")
print(" ")
os.system("mkdir wget")
os.system("move wget %userprofile%")
print(" ")
slowprint("Moving 1 tools (wget)...")
print(" ")
os.system("move wget.exe %userprofile%\wget")
print(" ")
slowprint("Changing Current Working Directory to wget folder...")
os.chdir('..\..\..\..')
os.chdir('\wget')
slowprint("Test execute 1 tools...")
print(" ")
os.system("wget")
print(" ")

choice = input("All required tools are ready. Do you want to install source PocketMine-MP? [y/n]: ")
if choice == 'n' : sys.exit()
if choice == 'y' : clear()
print("Loading...")
print("This might take a while based on your Internet Connection speed.")
os.system("wget -q https://jenkins.pmmp.io/job/PHP-8.0-Aggregate/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/PHP-8.0-Windows-x64.zip")
os.system("move PHP-8.0-Windows-x64.zip %userprofile%")
os.chdir('..')
phpextract()
clear()
slowprint("Installing PocketMine-MP....")
slowprint("Creating folder 'PMMP-Server'...")
os.chdir('\PMMP-Server')
slowprint("Getting all files from https://github.com & https://jenkins.pmmp.io...")
os.system("wget -q https://github.com/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/releases/latest/download/PocketMine-MP.phar")
os.system("wget -q https://github.com/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/releases/latest/download/start.cmd")
slowprint("Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) Setup detected. Do you want to install it?")
choice = input("Install it by typing [y], or if you have the program already, type [n]: ")
if choice == 'n' : print(" ")
if choice == 'y' : subprocess.call(['vc_redist.x64.exe'])
slowprint("All required source are ready. Open 'start.cmd' in Windows Explorer on folder %userprofile%\PMMP-Server or type 'start.cmd' in your cmd on folder %userprofile%\PMMP-Server")
slowprint("You can close this cmd window or end task python safely")
choice = input("Install the server now? [y/n]: ")
if choice == 'n' : slowprint("Why? I'll guess i'll never knew it..")
if choice == 'y' : os.system("start %userprofile%\PMMP-Server\start.cmd")
slowprint("Thank you for installing PocketMine-MP with our Setup.")
choice = input("Exit? The setup succesfully completed. [Type any key or 'y' and press enter]: ")
if choice == 'y' : sys.exit()
if choice == 'cocoball' : slowprint("Created with Notepad++ & Code Editor, Tested with Termux, Ubuntu, & Windows Command Prompt")
sys.exit()
```

Any solutions of fixing my code?

Comment: Why does the code do `os.system("move PHP-8.0-Windows-x64.zip %userprofile%")` after downloading the file, but then `os.chdir('..')`?  Shouldn't it just cd to the directory the file is actually in?

Comment: Oh.. yeah.. i forgot